# Unable to access certain websites, an issue with router/ISP?

Tags: router, website, connection

For the past few weeks, I'm unable to access particular websites from home.

I can't access LinkedIn.com, HSBC, paypal, the Project Kenai website, amongst others. I'm able to access facebook, fedora forums, and various other sites fine.

This behaviour is happning on all PCs on my home network, including my iPhone which uses my wifi connection

I have checked settings on my router, I can't see any indication that sites are blocked, I haven't altered settings in at least a year.

Could there be an issue with the router? It is at least 7 years old and has a tendancy to drop wirless connections at any point.

Or could this be an issue with my ISP? I'm on AOL UK Broadband (I think now part of TalkTalk)

Any suggestions? skype/MSN/games etc work ok, just not certain websites

traceroute below

```
[james@nevada ~]$ traceroute linkedin.com
traceroute to linkedin.com (64.74.98.86), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.527 ms  0.787 ms  1.444 ms
 2  host-92-2-192-1.as43234.net (92.2.192.1)  17.724 ms  21.611 ms  26.479 ms
 3  92.31.251.14 (92.31.251.14)  30.713 ms  35.032 ms  39.521 ms
 4  xe-9-3-0-scr001.loh.as13285.net (78.144.2.5)  46.566 ms  49.557 ms  54.434 ms
 5  xe-9-0-0-scr001.log.as13285.net (78.144.0.251)  58.915 ms  62.984 ms  133.507 ms
 6  xe-11-0-0-scr010.thn.as13285.net (78.144.1.0)  71.870 ms xe-10-2-0-scr010.thn.as13285.net (78.144.1.2)  19.833 ms  18.775 ms
 7  limelight-pp-thn.as13285.net (78.144.3.6)  84.206 ms  84.658 ms  95.032 ms
 8  tge11-1.fr4.lga.llnw.net (69.28.172.149)  113.535 ms  114.382 ms  116.334 ms
 9  tge8-4.fr3.ord.llnw.net (69.28.172.198)  144.027 ms  147.947 ms  152.501 ms
10  linkedin.tge3-4.fr3.ord.llnw.net (208.111.156.70)  158.394 ms  164.134 ms  167.226 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *^C
[james@nevada ~]$ traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (209.85.227.147), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1)  0.998 ms  1.285 ms  1.563 ms
 2  host-92-2-192-1.as43234.net (92.2.192.1)  17.286 ms  21.868 ms  25.789 ms
 3  92.31.251.46 (92.31.251.46)  30.251 ms  34.691 ms  38.805 ms
 4  xe-10-3-0-scr001.loh.as13285.net (78.144.2.7)  47.267 ms  50.070 ms  54.729 ms
 5  xe-11-0-0-scr010.sov.as13285.net (78.144.0.226)  59.212 ms  63.529 ms  68.020 ms
 6  google-pp-sov.as13285.net (78.144.5.6)  73.159 ms  18.074 ms  19.268 ms
 7  209.85.255.175 (209.85.255.175)  23.723 ms  27.836 ms  31.762 ms
 8  72.14.232.134 (72.14.232.134)  42.877 ms 66.249.95.170 (66.249.95.170)  48.771 ms 72.14.232.134 (72.14.232.134)  51.618 ms
 9  209.85.252.83 (209.85.252.83)  55.516 ms 216.239.49.45 (216.239.49.45)  61.170 ms 209.85.252.83 (209.85.252.83)  65.001 ms
10  209.85.243.97 (209.85.243.97)  71.559 ms  73.418 ms 209.85.243.89 (209.85.243.89)  78.560 ms
11  wy-in-f147.1e100.net (209.85.227.147)  83.499 ms  87.838 ms  92.990 ms
[james@nevada ~]$
```

Comment: Do you have a DLink router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check DNS and then with traceroute to see where it blocks.

Comment: thanks, just added traceroute output into my original post. As you can see google works fine but not linkedin

Comment: It looks like linkedin.com may be blocking.  I wonder if going through a public proxy would solve the problem.  There must be a misconfigured routing table somewhere on their side.  I had a similar problem and my ISP concluded the same thing, except they didn't control the misconfigured node.

Comment: The traceroute from LinkedIn is OK. I'm getting something similar but can access the web site.